# How to route to or navigate to a route programmatically in nextjs class component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, router

I am building a simple app using nextjs. most of my components are functional components. However, I have a class component to handle form.

I want to redirect to the home page after the form is submitted. `console.log(this.router)` gives undefined. Since it is a class component I can't use `useRouter()` hook. How do I get reference to router in class components in next.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got the answer,

```
import Router from 'next/router'
```

and use `Router.push(...)`

With Next 13 onwards, import router from `next/navigation`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using the `next/router` default export directly, `withRouter` HOC can also add the router object to any component.

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

class Page extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { router } = this.props
        return <p>{router.pathname}</p>
    }
}

export default withRouter(Page)
```